# AngularJS - ngRoute resolve depends on other resolves

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I have a resolve function that requires data retrieved in other resolve functions. I have found that using ui-router this can be accomplished using something like this:

```
resolve: {
    one: [
        () => {
            console.log("one");
            return 1;
        }
    ],

    two: [
        () => {
            console.log("two");
            return 2;
        }
    ],

    three: [
            "one",
            "two",
        (
            one,
            two
        ) => {
            console.log("three");
            return one + two;
        }
    ]
}
```

However, my workplace is using ngRoute instead of ui-router. Is there a technique with ngRoute that accomplishes the above?

**Edit**: For clarity, when doing the above I get "one" and "two" in the console but not "three".

Comment: What happen when you do that in `ngRoute`?

Comment: @georgeawg I edited with the results of the above code. Basically, three never resolves presumably because it is forever waiting for one and two.

Comment: I doubt that even UI-Router injects results of resolves into other resolver functions. It seems like a recipe for circular dependency problems. On the other hand, both ngRoute and UI-Router can inject services into resolver functions. I recommend re-factoring the code. Consolidate the three resolvers into one and return an object. Possibly with the help of `$q.all`.